# Filter PowerApps gallery by Dynamics lookup value

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, powerapps, dynamics-crm-365

Sorry this seems such a basic question but I simply cannot find an equivalent example anywhere!

Given a new PowerApp created from the "start from data" template against the native D365 Contact entity. The new app contains a Gallery control. I simply want to filter it to only show Contacts that match a specific account ID.

I believed this should be as simple as this, but I cannot get this or any permutation that I've tried to work (syntax errors). Where am I going wrong? I've set the Items property of the control to this, but it's just not right. Among a couple of hours of guesses, I've tried appending ".id" or "_id" to parentaccountid (in various case permutations) I don't know where else to look.

```
Filter('Contacts', parentaccountid = "dd12fc2e-ab9a-4488-bc62-22e3bc048cb7")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use **Lookup property** `_accountid_value` to accomplish this. [Lookup property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/contact?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#lookup-properties)

```
Filter('Contacts', _accountid_value = GUID("dd12fc2e-ab9a-4488-bc62-22e3bc048cb7"))
```

[Reference](https://www.cloudfronts.com/filter-records-in-gallery-control-based-on-value-selected-in-other-gallery-control-in-powerapps/)

Comment: Thank you @Arun-Vinoth! Your response was 90% there so I've edited it and marked as answer. Key points: 1) name property for comparison needs to start with underscore as you'd shown; 2)  property must be lowercase as you'd shown; 3) string must be cast to a GUID using     GUID("guid-as-string")